# Faster than dict way to assign index to strings python

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to take some large files of strings and replace each string with an id from 1 up in a separate file. There are repeats of some of the strings within each file, and there are common strings between files so those need to get the same id. I have implemented this with a dictionary, which works, but due to the size of the files and the amount of strings, this solution seems to work slowly. Is there a data structure or perhaps hashing technique that would be better suited for this?

______________________edited_______________________________________________________

My implementation for dict

```
index = {}
lastindex = 0
for row in reader:
    if row[0] not in index:
        lastindex += 1
        index[row[0]] = lastindex
    w.write(index[row[0]])
```

An input sample

```
feifei77.w70-e2.ezcname.com
reseauocoz.cluster007.ovh.net
cse-web-cl.comunique-se.com.br
ext-cust.squarespace.com
ext-cust.squarespace.com
ext-cust.squarespace.com
ext-cust.squarespace.com
ghs.googlehosted.com
isutility.web9.hubspot.com
sendv54sxu8f12g.ihance.net
sites.smarsh.io
www.triblocal.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
*.2bask.com
*.819.cn
```

this should return

```
1
2
3
4
4
4
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
...
```

I should clarify, it does not necessarily need to be ordered in that way, though it does need to include every integer from 1 to the number of strings.
4 2 3 1 1 1 1 5 6 7 8 9 10 would be valid as well

Comment: Your bottleneck is likely just the sheer volume of data you need to process. `dict`s are already highly optimized, but you'll need to show more detail (code, sample input, etc) if you want any specific suggestions.

Comment: Did you profile your code ? Python's `dict` are hash tables, and the lookup time is O(1), so I'm not sure your dict is the culprit.

Comment: I guess I was looking for a way to do this without storing all the strings in one memory bank, but I'm not sure if that is possible. A dict is fast, but if theres a way to do it through hashing, holding millions of strings is going to cost a lot more than that

Comment: What's exactly present in `row`?

Comment: row contains a few separate strings, but I am processing the other strings through separate ways. The first string in row is the only one I have to process like this.

Comment: I looks weird to me that you write out something on each index-operation. This should have a massive impact on runtime. Try batching writes, and only write out every now and then.

Comment: I have a file with 1 million of 30 character random strings. The above procedure (including input and output file operations) processes this file in about 2 seconds. Is this speed insufficient?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not getting that speed, maybe something else in my code is slowing it down? Thanks for the help

Comment: @deets your suggestion has helped with the speed, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly more memory friendly would be to use a `set` instead of a `dict`. Using the `unique_everseen()` example from the `itertools` docs at https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html you could do this:

```
for idx, word in enumerate(unique_everseen(reader), 1):
    print(idx)
```

An alternative that would scale to much larger data sets would be to use some sort of persistent key/value store that stores data on disk (instead of an in-memory mapping), e.g. with LevelDB (using Plyvel) it could look like this:

```
import itertools
import plyvel

db = plyvel.DB('my-database', create_if_missing=True)
cnt = itertools.count(1)  # start counting at 1
for word in reader:
    key = word.encode('utf-8')
    value = db.get(key)
    if value is not None:
        # We've seen this word before.
        idx = int(value)
    else:
        # We've not seen this word before.
        idx = next(cnt)
        db.put(key, str(idx).encode('ascii'))

    print(idx)
```

Comment: I'm still testing speed but so far this seems to work pretty well. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck of your code is the w.write during the for loop. Generate the dict first and then write the file it will run much faster.